# Storing passwords (tokens) in Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, github

We are moving from gitscm to github.  I have scm Eclipse projects where I put my git user name and token and stored it in secure storage.  Now we will be using github (same user name but new token) but I will also still be using the git scm.  If I store my git login and token in secure storage will it overwrite my gitscm passord or can it keep both of them and distinguish?  I tried doing a google search but did not find information I needed.

Comment: The secure storage stores the GitHub user/password separately. Try it and see preferences: _General > Security > Secure Storage_, tab _Contents_.